# Find in list in Django. Find single column

Tags: python, django

```
class A (models.Model):
name = models.charfield(max_length=200);
study = models.ForeignKey(Study);
b = models.CharField(max_length=200);

def__unicode__(self)
return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.id);
```

In my template i want to show the data from query

```
select name from A where id = 70.
```

I have the list for my template loaded, everything else works, but i can't get that name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries are assembled in the view, not the template.

```
A.objects.filter(id=70).values_list('name')
A.objects.get(id=70).name
```

Comment: Thanks, started with django yesterday and didn't know that the queries should be in the view... so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q = A.objects.get(pk=70)
Q.name
```

More details about [Django Querys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)